# codes for ADD,EDIT,DELETE,SEARCH in vb2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently working on my thesis in school and they required me to use VB2010 and MS ACCESS 2010.

what could be the easier way to connect and manipulate the DB? 
is it by using MS ACCESS 2003? or MS ACCESS 2007?

I need some help because I'm new to Visual Basic 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you googled about it - [insert update delete access vb.net](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=insert%20update%20delete%20access%20vb.net&aq=1&oq=insert%20update%20delete%20access%20with%20&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), there are lots of reference about this.

[Insert Update Delete Navigation & Searching In Access Database Using VB.NET](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/insert-update-delete-navigation-searching-in-access-databa)

- Create Visual Basic 2010 Project: VB-Access
- Assume that, we have a database file named data.mdb
- Place the data.mdb file into ..\bin\Debug\ folder 
  (Where the project executable file (.exe) is placed)

**what could be the easier way to connect and manipulate the DB?**
Use OleDBConnection class to make connection with DB

**is it by using MS ACCESS 2003 or MS ACCESS 2007?**
you can use any you want to use or your client will use on their machine.

it seems that you want to find some example of opereations fo the database. Here is  an example of Access 2010 for your reference:

Example code snippet:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class DBUtil

 Private connectionString As String

 Public Sub New()

  Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
  Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;"
  Dim dbSource = "Data Source=d:\DB\Database11.accdb"

  connectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

 End Sub

 Public Function GetCategories() As DataSet

  Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Categories"
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query)
  Return FillDataSet(cmd, "Categories")

 End Function

 Public SubUpdateCategories(ByVal name As String)
  Dim query As String = "update Categories set name = 'new2' where name = ?"
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name)
  Return FillDataSet(cmd, "Categories")

 End Sub

 Public Function GetItems() As DataSet

  Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Items"
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query)
  Return FillDataSet(cmd, "Items")

 End Function

 Public Function GetItems(ByVal categoryID As Integer) As DataSet

  'Create the command.
  Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE Category_ID=?"
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("category_ID", categoryID)

  'Fill the dataset.
  Return FillDataSet(cmd, "Items")

 End Function

 Public Sub AddCategory(ByVal name As String)

  Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

  'Create the command.
  Dim insertSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Categories "
  insertSQL &= "VALUES(?)"
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insertSQL, con)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", name)

  Try
   con.Open()
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  Finally
   con.Close()
  End Try

 End Sub

 Public Sub AddItem(ByVal title As String, ByVal description As String, _
    ByVal price As Decimal, ByVal categoryID As Integer)

  Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

  'Create the command.
  Dim insertSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Items "
  insertSQL &= "(Title, Description, Price, Category_ID)"
  insertSQL &= "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
  Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(insertSQL, con)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", title)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", description)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", price)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CategoryID", categoryID)

  Try
   con.Open()
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  Finally
   con.Close()
  End Try

 End Sub

 Private Function FillDataSet(ByVal cmd As OleDbCommand, ByVal tableName As String) As DataSet

  Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
  Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;"
  Dim dbSource = "Data Source=D:\DB\Database11.accdb"

  connectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
  con.ConnectionString = connectionString
  cmd.Connection = con
  Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
  Dim ds As New DataSet()

  Try
   con.Open()
   adapter.Fill(ds, tableName)
  Finally
   con.Close()
  End Try
  Return ds

 End Function

End Class
```

Refer these links:
[Insert, Update, Delete & Search Values in MS Access 2003 with VB.NET 2005](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26801/Insert-Update-Delete-Search-Values-in-MS-Access-20)
[INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE AND SELECT Data in MS-Access with VB 2008](http://www.setha.info/ict-vb2008/43-ict-vb2008-0011.html)
[How Add new record ,Update record,Delete Records using Vb.net Forms when Access as a back](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/305022-How-Add-new-record-Update-record-Delete-Records-using-Vb.net-Forms-Access-back.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the codes, I will study these codes further so that i'll be able to finish my program, but I don't see any delete query here.

Comment: I have a question, why do these lines of codes always appear? 
  
(Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection)
(Dim dbProvider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;")
(Dim dbSource = "Data Source=d:\DB\Database11.accdb")

Comment: because this line create connection between access file and the front hand code where you want to execute these queries.. well regarding your question check the reference links. but you should have little knowledge about SQL query.. Get some knowledge about these basic things then you can develop application

Comment: thank you sir! I will do that, it's kinda hard for me to understand it but anyway I will try my best.

Answer (score 0):

A good resource start off point would be [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401.aspx) as your looking into a microsoft product